# bxSlider not working despite best efforts

Tags: jquery, html, bxslider

I have tried everything I can think of and bxSlider will not work.  I have stripped it down to nothing but the slider inside a div and I just get a blank page when previewing.  I have tested paths and they are correct.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                autoControls: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sliderbox"> 
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img src="images/1.jpg" width="800" height="400" title="Hello World" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/2.jpg" width="800" height="400" title="Hello World" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/3.jpg" width="800" height="400" title="Hello World" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>        

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its is good to keep jquery and bxslider before .... `</body>.`

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                    auto: true,
                    autoControls: true
                });
            });
        </script>
</body>
```

[Here is The Link to Working Demo of Bx slider](https://codepen.io/gudboisgn/pen/gRYdoP)

HTML

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200?text=1" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200?text=2" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200?text=3" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200?text=4" /></li>
   <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200?text=5" /></li>
   <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200?text=6" /></li>
   <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200?text=7" /></li>
   <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200?text=8" /></li>
   <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200?text=9" /></li>
   <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200?text=10" /></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 9,
    slideWidth: 170,
    slideMargin: 10,
    ticker: false, //true
    speed: 20000
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I still get a blank page when testing.